# $L^p$ integrable but not $L^q$ integrable

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

Does there exist a **continuous** function on $[0, \infty)$  such that it is in $L^p(0,\infty)$ for some $p\in [1,2]$ but is not in $L^q(0,\infty)$ for any $q\in (2, 2/(2-p))$?

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: there is no inclusion between L^p (\Omega) and L^q(\Omega) if mes(\Omega)=\infty. Here I want to change a little: Find or disprove : there is a continuous function on [0,infty) which is in L^p(0,\infty) for p\in[1,2], but is not in L^q(0,\infty) for q=2/(2-p) (=\infty if p=2). I have found several examples, but all they have singularity at zero. The trouble is the continuity requirement. Especially, the continuity at zero. I tend to say no to this question. Such  function cannot approach zero at infinity. So it cannot be uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3):

For any $n\in\mathbb N$, put $\delta_n=\frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}$. Now, let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be the continuous function defined as follows: $f(t)\equiv e^n$ on $\left[n-\frac{\delta_n}2,n+\frac{\delta_n}2\right]$, $f(t)\equiv 0$ outside $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} [n-\delta_n, n+\delta_n]$, and $f$ is linear on the remaining intervals. Then $f$ is in $L^1(0,\infty)$ because $$\int_0^\infty \vert f(t)\vert dt= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac32\delta_n\times e^n=\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty\, .$$
On the other hand, $f$ is not in any $L^q$, $q>1$ since 
$$\int_0^\infty \vert f(t)\vert^q dt\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_n\times e^{qn}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{(q-1)n}}{n^2}=\infty\, . $$

Comment: Nice construction. +1

Comment: Yes,user80469. Thank you so much. This function consists of a series of trapezoids whose height grow exponentially and width shrink to zero, maintain a finite area and "higher area" is infinite.   This is a similar construction to the construction of a continuous integrable function which does not exist limit at infinity.

Comment: This really is a nice construction. Is there also a simpler non-continuous function on that interval that is only $L^1$ integrable?

Comment: You can take $f(t)=\frac{1}{t(\log t)^2}$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $f(t)=0$ elsewhere.